# How to install Guice in Scala / SBT?

Tags: scala, guice, sbt

I have found this Maven repository for Guice http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/

I am wondering how do I insert this to `.sbt` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this line.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
```

More on [SBT Wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management)

Comment: I'm getting a `[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.inject#guice_2.9.2;3.0: not found`?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to me `%` instead of `%%`.